# Unable to reinstall mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm having a hard time reinstalling Mongodb from scratch.

I've gone through all the steps in the following link:

But when I try to run mongo after the install I'm getting the following error:

● mongodb.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)

```
May 16 16:52:24 synctup-stage systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
May 16 16:54:07 synctup-stage systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
May 16 16:54:07 synctup-stage systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
May 16 16:54:07 synctup-stage systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
May 16 16:54:07 synctup-stage systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
May 16 16:55:45 synctup-stage systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
May 16 16:55:45 synctup-stage systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
May 16 16:55:45 synctup-stage systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
May 16 17:06:19 synctup-stage systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
May 16 17:06:19 synctup-stage systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

Any advice on what I can look at the fix this???

Thanks!!

My current mongodb.service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented >database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: This looks more like a services question, rather than mongodb, but it looks like you need to add `ExecStop` to your `mongodb.service` file. Try adding this under your `ExecStart` line: `ExecStop=/bin/kill $MAINPID`

Comment: could you remove --quiet form ExecStart , this should give a verbose output why mongo is failing.